# Getting error http request failed: null when using path in karate

Tags: java, karate, gherkin

I'm starting to use karate for testing, but when I use the "path" keyword, I receive a "http request failed: null" error.

When using the following scenario, it works:

```
Feature: items

Scenario: Testing /items response status
    Given url appBaseUrl + '/items'
    And param param1 = 1
    And param param2 = 10
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

But when I try using the "path" keyword like in the following code, I end up getting the error

```
Feature: items

Scenario: Testing /items response status
    Given url appBaseUrl
    And path 'items'
    And param param1 = 1
    And param param2 = 10
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

```
items.feature:8 - null
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: items.feature:8 - null
    at ✽.When method GET (items.feature:8)
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Is there some additional step that needs to be done and that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else going on, because this should work. Try this for example:

```
* def appBaseUrl = 'http://httpbin.org/anything'

Given url appBaseUrl
And path 'items'
And param param1 = 1
And param param2 = 10
When method get
Then status 200
```

Works fine on my system.

So I suggest you follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

EDIT: this was indeed a bug: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/760 - and using `karate-jersey` is a workaround until the fix

Comment: Your example worked for me, but as soon as I changed the url to http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1, I started getting the error again.

Comment: And since the first code I posted works, I'm sure that the server is running and working properly

Comment: @Gruutak there is only one way now for you to prove there is a problem :) your move